# Interpolar animation in google maps for flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

How is it possible to update the marker location smoothly on flutter mobile app.

With the current approach the marker is jusmping to the new location. I wanted to have a smooth movement like uber vehicles LatLong are from firestore.

here is my current Approach

```
double latitude = double.parse(value.docs[b]['lat']);
double longitude = double.parse(value.docs[b]['lon']);
var markerIdVal = value.docs[b].id;
            
            final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

            final Marker marker = Marker(
              markerId: markerId,
              position: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
              icon: carIcon,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`flutter_animarker`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker) package. It includes features lie marker's position animation, multiple markers' animations at the same time, etc. The whole feature list as per the documentation:

> - Marker's position animation
> - Multiple markers' animations at the same time
> - Null-safety compatible
> - Ripple effect over marker position
> - Marker's rotation or bearing/heading of direction
> - Multipoint linear animation (Piecewise Linear Approximation Algorithm)
> - Support animation curves and duration
> - Widget-based with fully customized behaviors
> - Animation warm-up for improving performance
> - Useful LocationTween, AngleTween and PolynomialLocationInterpolator core logic

Comment: It doesent it just applies a ripple. But I get lat lon on markers by reading the database then calling update maker function

Comment: I have tried using animarker but the issue is that the camera position centers to the overall center of markers when a marker moves